# Custom Angular Module, VsCode intellisense doesn't work for component

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, ng-packagr

I've created an external module for angular and when i try to use it in my other project, VsCode doesn't understand the component tags.

I'm using ng-packagr to create the module.

example:

```
<ag-button-delete (agClick)="test()"></ag-button-delete>

[Angular]
'ag-button-delete' is not a known element:
1. If 'ag-button-delete' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ag-button-delete' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

but if i do ng serve or even ng build --prod --aot it does work as intended...

what am i missing in my custom module package to get the intellisense for VsCode ?

I'm using ng-packagr to create the module.